# CSS Align items in a column depending on content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have the following html code with own css and bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">91.86</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+61%)</span>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">108.15</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+108%)</span>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">329.93</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+593%)</span>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.table-string {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: end;
}
```

I need to recieve column like this:

[image]

But actually get this:

[image]

How to align values without percentages in a column so that they are strictly under each other: hundreds under hundreds, tens under tens, ones under ones? And also value and percentage must be aligned at the end of the field. Thanks for any help

Comment: @connexoi I forgot to mention that I also use bootstrap

Comment: This is so simple it hurts. (Not accounting for the middle arrow symbol) you simply need two 50% width child elements with the content aligned right/left respectively. If the center arrows symbol is necessary, than what you need is for the elements on its left and right to be flex 1

Comment: @connexo i use text-align: end to aligned text in p at the end

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this could be the solution, but I need these values to be aligned at the end of the field, not in the middle

Comment: Aligning a parent element has nothing to do with how its child elements are aligned ;) If you use a table with columns.... you should add more context to your question. It's no clear from only your image what's the entire picture.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary solution, you can use something like this. Just set the `width: 50%;` of your `<p>` and `<span>` tags.

```css
.table-string {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: end;
}
span.ml-2 {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">91.86</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+61%)</span>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">108.15</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+108%)</span>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
    <p class="table-string">329.93</p>
    <span class="ml-2">(+593%)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With Bootstrap there is usually no need to add extra CSS but by adding it we provide more chances for Bootstrap standard CSS to screw up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide your row into 2 equal halves and align text depending

```
<div class="row" style="width:10rem">
    <p class="col-6 p-1 text-end">91.86</p>
    <span class="col-6  p-1 text-start">(+61%)</span>
</div>
```

and this is an [example](https://codepen.io/Ahmed-elbessfy/pen/gOGpgMR?editors=1010)

Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

Remove `d-flex` from all the Div's and put `d-inline` onto all `<p>`'s and `<span>`'s instead. With this you most likely do not need the CSS for `.table-string` so remove that as well.

Eg

```
<p class="d-inline">91.86</p>
<span class="ml-2 d-inline">(+61%)</span>
```

Comment: But if it solve my problem?

Comment: It might, I am too busy to test it at the moment but it is usually what I would do. Give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you are using Bootstrap, and if I understood your question, you just need to add two classes to the flex item, `flex-column` `align-items-end`, in order to set the direction of flex items and change the alignment on the cross axis:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
[…]
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items` is for vertical alignment.

Comment: @christo We can use `align-items-*` on the content itself. Eg one of the OP's `<p>` tags.  But `justify-content-*` is perfect for use on the parent Div. So you can format the content directly or by editing it's parent div.